Liquidar Tiempos (Dias - Horas - Minutos)
Me hacen el siguiente requerimiento para cobrar el tiempo de un vehículo al interior de un aparcadero:
Valor x 15min: $800; Valor x 1h: $3000

Se cobran los primeros dos lapsos de tiempo de 15min es decir hasta el minuto 30
A partir del minuto 31 se cobra 1h hasta el minuto 60
A partir del minuto 61 se acumula y comienza el nuevo ciclo
Liquidar de acuerdo a las horas y minutos

.
//calculo la diferencia de tiempo entre la entrada y la salida
$start_date = new DateTime($ordet_date_in);
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($ordet_date_out));

// total minutos esto lo esta dando bien
$minutes = $since_start->days * $daysTotal * 60;  // Dias
$minutes += $since_start->h * 60;                 // Horas
$minutes += $since_start->i;                      // Minutos
$ordet_total_time = $minutes;                     // Total Minutos

// horas de 60min ok
$hoursTotal = $ordet_total_time / 60;
$hoursTotal = intval($hoursTotal);
           
// le resto los minutos al total
$minutesRestantes = $ordet_total_time - ($hoursTotal*60);

//aqui debo contar cuantos lapsos de tiempo de 30min hay en el residuo de minutos
$minsx30 = $minutesRestantes / 30;

// debe de haber 1 y pedazo por que ya saque las horas x cada lapso de 30 se suma 1 hora
if ($minsx30 > 1) {
 $hoursTotal += 1; 
 $minutesRestantes -= 60;
}

// busco los lapsos de 15min de aquí en adelante no me da
$minsx15 = $minutesRestantes / 15;
$minsx15Int = intval($minsx15);

// liquidación
$vrTotalHours = $hoursTotal * 3000;
$vrtotalx15 = $minsx15 * 800;

debo presentar los tiempo a liquidar y el total
La pregunta es: hay alguna forma, mas directa, de calcular los lapsos de tiempo, es decir desmenuzar los minutos hasta que se acaben?

no se como en 211 min hay 4 horas... igual, ni siquiera entiendo cual es tu problema...

211/60 = 3.5166_  o 3 horas y 31 minutos ... de donde sacas ese otro calculo ?

@Excorpion esta claro ... 3 horas + 1 hora (31 min) = 4 horas, lo que no queda claro es de donde sale el lapso de los 29 minutos...

@FranciscoNuñezIALover Si, esa omisión desvió la pregunta, ya la edité.

@wings77 la pregunta que acabas de formular, está basada en opiniones. No va a problemas de código en este caso (como era la anterior). Es como... ¿Hay una forma mejor de hacer esto? puede que si, puede que no, y ahi entran las opiniones. Actualmente no tienes problemas con el codigo presentado cierto? si es asi, hay que cerrar la pregunta debido a que no hay un problema por resolver.

@wings77 cual es el problema con el codigo ???

Veo un problema más matemático que otra cosa. No hay que "desmenuzar los minutos hasta que se acaben", solo usar las funciones matemáticas adecuadas para ir consumiendo los valores. Entonces, para atacar este problema debes:

Primero verificar cuántas horas han pasado, a esas le aplicas la tarifa horaria.
Luego, a los minutos restantes (este numero siempre será < 60):

Si es mayor a 30, le aplicas la tarifa de 1 hora.
De lo contrario le aplicas 0, 1, 2 veces la tarifa de 15 min.



Vamos a verlo con un ejemplo, suponiendo la siguiente entrada y salida:
$entrada = new DateTime('2024-06-14 10:52:32');
$salida  = new DateTime('2024-06-14 14:10:18');
$min_dif = intval(($salida->getTimestamp() - $entrada->getTimestamp()) / 60); // 197

$horas = intdiv($min_dif, 60); // 3
$total = $horas * 3000 // 9000

Ahora solo falta la lógica para los minutos restantes:
$min_restantes = $min_dif % 60; // 17
if($min_restantes > 30) {
     $total += 3000;
} else {
     $cant_15min = ceil($min_restantes / 15) // 2
     $total += $cant_15min * 800;
}

Aclarado el concepto, ahora se puede hacer una función más formal, que devuelva un array con el desglose del tiempo, los costos y el total:
<?php
define('TARIFA15', 800);
define('TARIFA60', 3000);

function getReport(string $date_in, string $date_out):array {
    $c60 = $c30 = $c15 = 0;
    $entrada = new DateTime($date_in);
    $salida  = new DateTime($date_out);
    $min_dif = intval(($salida->getTimestamp() - $entrada->getTimestamp()) / 60);
    $horas = intdiv($min_dif, 60); // Division entera, php 7+
    $c60 = $horas * TARIFA60;
    
    $min_restantes = $min_dif % 60;
    $res = ['minutes'=>$min_dif, 'hours'=>$horas, 'subtHour'=>$c60, 'minRem'=>$min_restantes];
    
    if($min_restantes > 30) {
        $c30 = TARIFA60;
        $res = array_merge($res, ['fraction'=>'+30_min', 'subtFr'=>$c30]);
    } else {
        $cant15min = ceil($min_restantes / 15);
        $c15 = $cant15min * TARIFA15;
        $res = array_merge($res, ['fraction'=>"$cant15min x 15_min", 'subtFr'=>$c15]);
    }
    $res['total'] = $c60 + $c30 + $c15;
    return $res;
}

El resultado de la función es un array asociativo, con la suficiente información para construir la factura al usuario.
Un ejemplo de salida:
echo json_encode(getReport('2024-06-14 10:52:32', '2024-06-14 14:10:18'));

{
    "minutes" : 197,
    "hours" : 3,
    "subtHour" : 9000,
    "minRem" : 17,
    "fraction" : "2 x 15_min",
    "subtFr" : 1600,
    "total" : 10600
}

